# changing /var in running system

Tags: filesystems, mount, fstab

I have the challenge that I cannot start a CentOS Linux server in single-user-mode, but I need to change the `/var` (currently part of /) to a new disk.
My way would be:

- mount the new disk on a temporary mount point: /tmp_var
- rsync -av /var /tmp_var
- add the new disk in the /etc/fstab (at the bottom)
- reboot

i have double checked the file permissions but i always get:

```
type=1400 audit(1410535874.353:4): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=701 comm="dmesg" path="/var/log/dmesg" dev=dm-1 ino=132049 scontext=system_u:system_r:dmesg_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 tclass=file
Entering non-interactive startup

Calling the system activity data collector (sadc)... Cannot open /var/log  /sa/sa12: Permission denied
```

Comment: 1) you do not mount a disk, but a filesystem, have you formated it ? 2) data under original /var will be hidden if you sucess, is that OK ? (if you intend to reclain space, then no)

Comment: 1) yes
2) that's ok

Comment: You probably need to give rsync the `-X` and `-A` options, to preserve selinux contexts.

Comment: that's it but i have disabled selinux